# Excel - check values in multiple columns and return the sum of a third column

Tags: excel

I am very well aware that similar questions have been asked many times before but somehow the answers don't work for me. So I am sharing my example with you and hope for your assistance.

[image: Excel snapshot]

Please see the attached example.

I want to return the sum of the **Amount** column, but only if ***all*** of the following criteria is met:

1. The value of Category is **1**
2. The value of Eligible is **Yes**
3. The value of Currency is **GBP**

The sum that should be returned is 9000 in this example.
But since I have hundreds of values like these, I need a formula to do it.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need SUMIFS. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function

Comment: =SUMIFS(D2:D12,A2:A12,1,B2:B12,"Yes",C2:C12,"GBP")

Comment: @usmanhaq should put it as a full answer, then lbjh may click on the tick to remove this question from "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D12,A2:A12,1,B2:B12,"Yes",C2:C12,"GBP")
```

You have to change the range references according to your data.